# Append to dropdownlist on change, ajax call, mvc list

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I ran into a little problem while doing this. Currently I have a script that loads the statelist on page load. Great right, its cascading with the countylist so whenever a state is changed it sends an ajax call to the server and then gets the countylist items into the countylist dropdown depending on the state. Now I want to do something a little different while keeping the same functionality. I want to be able to get the State and County on one-click #load. So once I hit load it will send an ajax call to the server and get a state and county name back that is tied to that load call. But here's there problem, I can change the statelist value to the state but then it doesn't change the countylist at all. The county list is completely null, so I have to open the statelist and click on the statelist to load the county list. I tried using on load, click, change etc. But it doesn't work so I am wondering if you can help me. Enough of me talking here is some code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var $stateList = $("#StateList");
  $stateList.change(function () {
    var statelist = $stateList[0];
    var countylist = $("#CountyList");
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      cache: false,
      url: "GetCounties",
      data: { "jsonString": statelist[statelist.selectedIndex].value },
      success: function (data) {
        countylist.empty();
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
        {
          countylist.append('<option value="' + data[i] + '">' + data[i] + '</option>');
        }
      }
    });
  });
  var statelist = $("#StateList");
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    url: "GetState",
    data: { "jsonOrderInt": orderdetailid.value },
    success: function (data) {
      statelist.val(data)
    }
  });
  var countyname = $("#CountyList");
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    url: "GetCountyName",
    data: { "jsonOrderInt": orderdetailid.value },
    success: function (data) {
      countyname.val(data)
    }
  }
});
```

Those are all separate ajax calls. One calls the countylist to show on change the other two are trying to get the state and county detail. I've been stumped on this for a while maybe you can help!

Comment: Mot sure I understand, but your last 2 ajax calls are outside the `$stateList.change(function ()` and will only be called once on initial page load. And what is `orderdetailid.value`? And you can replace `statelist[statelist.selectedIndex].value` with `statelist.val()`

Comment: @StephenMuecke orderdetail.value is the integer I use that has a statelist and countylist value on the server side that I enter when needed, it has a county name and state name tied to it.

Comment: I'm not clear on what your trying to do. Are you expecting the last 2 ajax calls to run when you select a State?

Comment: @StephenMuecke not exactly it is two seperate peices. One is a cascading dropdown, statelist(which is already loaded) and countylist(which loads dynamically). The other two calls are me wanting to append(not the right word) a state and county name to the dropdownlists. Basically I put the number 1 into orderdetailid and it should return me a state(MI, which it does) and a county (wayne). BUT, when I `   success: function (data) {
      statelist.val(data)
    }` it doesnt do this `        {
          countylist.append('<option value="' + data[i] + '">' + data[i] + '</option>');
        } ``

Comment: I still don't understand. The only time the last 2 ajax calls will be made is when the page initially loads (at which point the countyname list isn't even populated so how could it select something?)